# Can DFS be used for star pattern recognition?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I am studying Artificial Intelligence. I was taking a lecture on Neural Networks and as an example problem my teacher took the example of counting all the stars in observable universe. The discussion continued and stopped on pattern matching. Since time was up he asked us to try and think about solving this problem using all the algorithms that we have previously studied, which include DFS, BFS, A*, Greedy, Simulated Annealing and Genetic Algorithm.
Now, I have no idea what he meant by that. I mean how is it even possible? Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: This post doesn't seem to have a clear question. Stack Overflow questions are generally expected to have a single point, which can be answered directly and completely in a single answer. Additionally, questions are expected to be useful to future users, and your question seems to be very specifically about your lecturer and studies. I recommend editing your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think DFS can't be used for Pattern Recognition because pattern recognition need learning process and DFS can't do learning process. You need machine learning technique to do learning process.
among the available list, you can use Genetic Algorithm or Neural Network. 

The simplest Pattern Recognition i ever done is Character Recognition with ANN Learning Vector Quantization (LVQ).LVQ